# Is heaven permanent in the Vedas?

Tags: scripture, vedas, heaven

We find in the Bhagavad Gita that Heaven is temporary by verse 21 of chapter 9 which reads:

> they, having enjoyed the vast heaven-world, when their merits are exhausted, enter the world-of-the-mortals; thus abiding by the injunctions of the three (vedas) , desiring (objects of) desires, they attain to the state of going-and-returning (samsara) .

So what's the stance of the Vedas on wether Heaven is permanent or temporary? However I do not want a verse from the Upanishads, I want verses only from the Samhtias Brahmanas etc.